# Can I configure Theano's x divided by 0 behavior

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I have a little problem using Theano. It seems that a `division by 0` results in `inf` not as using e.g. Numpy this results in 0 (at least the inverse function do behave like that). Take a look:

```
from theano import function, sandbox, Out, shared
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

reservoirSize   = 7
_eye            = np.eye(reservoirSize)

gpu_I = shared( np.asarray(_eye, np.float32 ) )

simply_inverse = function(
[],
Out(sandbox.cuda.basic_ops.gpu_from_host(
    T.inv( gpu_I )
    ),
    borrow=True
    )
)

gpu_wOut = simply_inverse()
Wout     = np.linalg.inv(_eye)

print "gpu_wOut:\n"
print np.asarray(gpu_wOut)

print "\nWout:\n"
print np.asarray(Wout)
diff_wOut = np.asarray(gpu_wOut) - Wout
diff_wOut = [ diff_wOut[0][i] if diff_wOut[0][i] > epsilon else 0  for i in range(reservoirSize)]
print "\n\nDifference of output weights: (only first row)\n"
print np.asarray(diff_wOut)
```

Results:

```
gpu_wOut:

[[  1.  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf   1.  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf   1.  inf  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf   1.  inf  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf   1.  inf  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf  inf   1.  inf]
 [ inf  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf   1.]]

Wout:

[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]


Difference of output weights (only first row):

[  0.  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf  inf]
```

This is a problem for some of my calculations I want to perform in my GPU and I don't want to get back the data from it to replace `inf` by `0` to continue my calculations of course since this would slow down the process considerably.

Comment: At no point does `numpy` divide by 0 in your code... - your matrix is not singular, so the determinant is non-zero

Comment: Inverting all elements means to calculate (x_*ij*)^(-1) which means for elements equal to zero 1/0. But for whatever reason this is happening anywar I need a solution for a situation like this `T.inv(T.dot(A,B) + const * eye)`

Comment: I'm confused.  It might just be that I don't grok tensor math anymore (if I ever did), but is there any reason to assume that the tensor inverse of a matrix is equal to the inverse of the matrix?

Comment: @StefanR.Falk: You do understand that the theano tensor reciprocal and the numpy matrix inverse are completely different mathematical opertions, don't you?

Comment: Please explain the difference between reciprocal and inverse value. 
tensor.inv(a) Returns a variable representing the inverse of a, ie 1.0/a. Also called reciprocal.

Comment: You could read the documentation: [tensor reciprocal](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#tensor.inv), [matrix inverse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html#numpy.linalg.inv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theano.tensor` calculates the *elementwise* inverse

`np.linalg.inv` calculates the inverse *matrix*

These are not the same thing mathematically

---

You're probably looking for the **experimental** [`theano.sandbox.linalg.ops.MatrixInverse`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/linalg.html#theano.sandbox.linalg.ops.MatrixInverse)